# Questions on certs

Tags: discussion

Was about to just delete this question but what are people's thoughts on it? Should certification questions be allowed? If this is one of the real questions it definitely should not be IMO, but I can't say whether it is or not.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24059/dev401-certification-question-data-model-dashboard

Comment: It looks like this question is from [here](http://www.proprofs.com/quiz-school/story.php?title=salesforce-401-dev). No idea where they got their questions from - looks a bit dodgy to be honest...

Comment: It doesn't look like a real question to me - words such as 'considered' and 'may' would require candidates to make assumptions and this would be weeded out early in the process.

Answer (score 8):

**No. I think they should be closed/deleted**

While questions on the certification process, or where to get information should be ok, I do not think this should be the case for the multiple choice questions used in real or mock exams.

1. I do not think we should be collecting a catalogue of certification examples or answers.
2. If certifications are to express a level of knowledge, that's knowledge that needs to be obtained by a person, and they should know/learn how to get answers from the official documentation and resources.

Comment: That Q was deleted SOOOOOOO quickly.

Comment: well, still not too bad to have an open discussion about it.

Comment: it's open :-) isn't it?

Comment: I just totally agree with you answer BTW, Maybe we need to have such an exam if users want to register to SFSE ?  ^^

Comment: I feel torn, really. I agree with this answer. But on the other hand the community is crying out for a good source of practice questions that are maintained with releases, and a stack-exchange-like forum would be a great way to do this. The reason I agree is I just don't feel this, a forum on how to get things done on the platform, is the right place for it. So questions on process, thumbs up. Thumbs down on practice exam questions.